# Display text information with scripts that use the 'timeframe' argument

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a script that uses the `timeframe` argument:

```
indicator ("My script", timeframe="D")
```

I would like to display some short text information on its chart (at any location), but I cannot find any way to do it. That is because this argument does not allow you to use drawings on the chart. It is written in the [Pine manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_indicator), and indeed, it did not work for me. I tried things such as `label.new`, `table.new`, `box.new` and `line.new`.

It did work with `plotshape`, but sadly, its text argument only accepts constant string variables, so you cannot use it to display a variable whose value is changing when the script is running. So it is no help for me.

Is there any way to overcome this limitation and have text details displayed on these type of charts?

Thank you!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pine Drawings are the only way to display non-constant string values on the chart, and the drawings do not work with the `timeframe=` parameter of the `indicator()` function, so there is no way to resolve this issue from that side.

Another approach is possible, though: use `request.security()` to request data from another timeframe instead of the `timeframe=` parameter. As long as the data you request from `security` has no drawings, the script will work fine, and you can still add a table/label in other parts of the script.